# SSMS Query store keeps getting disabled

Tags: sql-server, ssms, query-store

I activated query store about a month ago with the settings below. Now, every morning starting up SSMS I find the Query store folder gone and query store disabled. Initially I used 1 Gb size, but changed it to five once it started disabling. This did not alleviate the problem. I found nothing about this with google. I'm using SSMS 18.9.2. and SQL Server 14.0.3411.3. What could be causing this problem? Last server reboot was over a week ago and I've activated it twice since, so this does not seem to be the cause.

[image: Query store parameters]

Comment: what does 

SELECT actual_state_desc, desired_state_desc, current_storage_size_mb,
 max_storage_size_mb, readonly_reason
FROM sys.database_query_store_options;

show ?

Comment: Do you deploy from Visual Studio?  If the database project settings there don't have Query Store enabled then it will disable it to match.

Comment: @JonathanFite No, it's a Dynamics Nav database, which i have tampered with directly from SSMS. But the structure (e.g. indexes) is maintained from the Nav development environment. Could it be that it resets when our ERP partner drops some other changes into the production database? I would find it far fetched that such an operation would reset all parameters, but I'll have to ask.

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64 I activated it this morning, and your query once again shows that actual_state_desc=ERROR and desired_state_desc=OFF. Current and desired sizes are 910 and 5000, and readonly_reason = 0. So it has apparently run into some error. Would you happen to know how to find out what error has been encountered?

Comment: An externally managed database?  I wouldn't put it past them to turn off Query Store on the regular to prevent you from doing what you are doing (i.e. easily forcing specific plans).

Comment: error logging doesn't seem to be QueryStore's strong point

Comment: @JonathanFite To some extent yes, but they seem to be not very qualified, hence I had to start being the DBA as well :). I'm almost certain they are not doing it on purpose, but I'll ask if they have some automation that could cause this. I suppose they don't know, though.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a native procedure to fix this, upwards from SQL Server 2017. I found the below code from a site I no longer remember, which fixed the issue for me, at least for now:

```
USE db_name
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_query_store_options WHERE actual_state=3)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    ALTER DATABASE [db_name] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF
    EXEC dbo.sp_query_store_consistency_check
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber 
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity 
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState 
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure 
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine 
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH;  
END
```

It cleared the ERROR state and restored the READ_WRITE mode.

Comment: my search engine would suggest it was this one :- https://tracyboggiano.com/archive/2018/06/query-store-error-state/

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64 That could have been it, although I feel I saw the same code in a few places. I ran it without setting the read_write mode explicitly, and even though the desired state was 0 in query store options, actual and desired states were still restored to read_write (2).